# Scroll handler only working on mousewheel, How to detect touchpad aswell?

Tags: javascript, events

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
});
```

is not working on touchpad, on mousewheel only works for mouse, the above works for scrollbars, how do I get something to work on *any* form of scroll, even when overflow is set to hidden?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the `touch` events like `touchstart` and `touchend` instead of the `scroll` event.

Comment: How about `wheel`?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event

Comment: make it an answer and I'll mark it